# How do I make any C++ library I make thread safe?

Tags: c++, memory-management, thread-safety

First of all, I'm fairly experienced with C++ and understand the basics of threading and thread synchronization. I also want to write a custom memory allocator as a pet project of mine and have read that they should be thread-safe.

I understand what the term "thread-safe" means, but I have no idea on how to make C++ code thread-safe.

Are there any practical examples or tutorials on how to make code thread-safe?

In a memory allocator scenario, is it essentially ensuring that all mutating functions are marked as critical sections? Or is there something more to it?

Comment: "How do i make any C++ library i make thread safe?" is a *huge* question.  There's no single best approach that works for everything.

Comment: An allocator is probably a bad place to start with thread safety.  Making an efficient allocator that is thread safe can be *really hard*.  I think you need to do some basic multithreaded programs first to get an idea of the challenges.

Comment: @cHao I can imagine that being the case, and I know how SO (as well as other StackExchange sites) are when it comes to broad questions. I was honestly hoping for helpful pointers and tips as I know I probably won't receive a concrete answer, but I do hope this is okay as I think it would be helpful for any other person thinking the same thing.

Comment: @SoapBox thanks for the input. Pardon my naivete, but I have worked on some basic multithreaded applications and have witnessed the fundamental challenges of multithreaded programs, e.g. deadlock, race conditions, synchronization problems, etc, but this has all been part of very small university tutorials. Furthermore, at work I have worked with libraries that have been made thread safe by other teams in our department and I now wish to create something a bit larger (not impossibly so) so that I get a bit more experience with thread-safety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as all threading issues: make sure that when one thread is changing something, no other thread is accessing it. For a memory allocation system, I would imagine you would need a way of making sure you don't allocate the same block of memory to 2 threads at the same time. Whether that is by wrapping the entire search, or by allowing multiple searches but locking when the allocation table is to be updated (which could then cause the result of the search to become invalid, necessitating another search) would be up to you.